# VBScript copy a file from a Network Server to another Network Server

Tags: vba, vbscript, windows-server-2003

I want to copy a file from

```
\\Server\SharedFolder\NameOfFile.txt
```

to

```
\\Server2\SecondSharedFolder\NameOfFile - 1-10-2012.txt
```

I can copy and rename the file on the local drive. I am having trouble access the file called NameOfFile.txt

I get the following error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error (50, 9) : File not found
```

Here is the offending code

```
fso.CopyFile SourcePath, DestinationPath, True
```

Comment: I was just going to ask you, what are the values of `SourcePath` and `DestinationPath` when you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SourcePath had a missing "\"